# Is there any way to get a drag start event from Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I have a simple drag/drop implementation:

```
private void appt_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Explorer oExplorer = OlApp.ActiveExplorer();
    Outlook.Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;

    foreach (object _obj in oSelection)
    {
        if (_obj is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            after = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)_obj;
        }
    }
    << send it where it needs to go >>
}
```

But I am now wanting to add a "drop here" overlay. The problem is, I intend for users to drop Outlook appointments into my app and I can't figure out how to tap into the drag start event when it occurs outside of my application.  Try as I might, Google failed me (or I'm rusty).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be concerned about the Drag Start, just handle the DragEnter/DragOver/Drop events:

- In your control, set AllowDrop="True"
- Add event handlers for DragEnter and Drop events, optionally also for DragOver if you want to provide fancy feedback

To get the text of the appointment, you can use e.Data.GetData("Text"). Unfortunately, it seems undocumented how to get at the other appointment data. e.Data.GetData("RenPrivateAppointment") sounds interesting (see also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d892d380-6b88-450b-b849-2eef761a50b7/dragdrop-event-in-outlook-calendar?forum=vsto)).

Comment: I'm handling those, but drag enter and over only occur once they get into my window, but I want my app to have the overlay show even when they're still dragging inside the Outlook window.

Comment: I doubt this would be possible

Comment: I was afraid of that, though I'm looking into the System Runtime Interop to see if maybe there's something in there that exposes OS events. As for the last part of your answer, my code in the question gets the data from the appointment -- you don't actually pull it from the object that's dropped, you get it from what is "selected" in Outlook, and when you drag an appointment, it always becomes selected.